# Failed to create maven project with maven-archetype-webapp

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

When I tried to create a Maven project with maven-archetype-webapp, some problems came out.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Creating maven-archetype-webapp".
org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException

An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Dependencies".
org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
```

I have tried a lot of solutions related to this, nothing worked.

How can I solve this?Thanks!

ps:I was using `eclipse 4.4.1` and `m2e 1.5.0`